# Motion5 replicator can not randomize?

Tags: software, motion

We all know and use the replicate option in Motion5 and it works great. 
but I can not find the option to randomize the start offset, or how to do this. So just a double check to hear from fellow users. 
*Let's say you have the one single band EQ in the timeline.it moves greatly up and down like a real equalizer meter would do. But this is just 1 bar, and I want at least 10 or 20 or 30 of them posed next to each other, like a real equalizer look.  ok the replicator makes a great option to clone it 30 times or any number. Perfectly and nice 30 peaces of audiobars, next to each other. Looks like a real EQ window now, but one big problem: They are all moving the exact same , all going up and all going down in the same time.* I tried to insert a randomizer. but this did not do the job to randomize the offset start point, and make them look moving all different up and down. Of course there is another solution: I can copy the 1 single bar EQ, and pasting it 30 times.

**Is Copying the single bar EQ and pasting it 30 times the only way to get this done?** The randomizer is supposed to do the job and I cannot fix this. **Did I mis something? Hope to hear from anyone soon and thanks a lot!**